# MWE function error message saying "use of undeclared indentifier"

Tags: objective-c

I'm unsure about how to make MWE with Objective C, so if you need anything else let me know.

I am trying running through a tutorial on building an iPhone app and have gotten stuck defining a function. I keep getting an error message saying "use of undeclared indentifier". However I believe I have initiated the function.

In the view controller I have:

```
if (scrollAmount > 0) {
    moveViewUp = YES;  
    [scrollTheView:YES];
}
else{ 
    moveViewUp = NO;
}
```

with the function under it

```
- (void)scrollTheView:(BOOL)movedUp {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp){
        rect.origin.y -= scrollAmount;
    }
    else {
        rect.origin.y += scrollAmount;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I have initiated the function in the header file (that I have imported).

```
- (void)scrollTheView:(BOOL)movedUp;
```

Comment: I don't see a declaration for scrollAmount in your function. Is it an instance variable? If so, then try self.scrollAmount.

Comment: I think I have fixed it by removing the square brackets.